# HttpClient with WebRequestHandler returns invalid cached response

Tags: c#, caching, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, dotnet-httpclient

We have stumble unto a problem while using `WebRequestHandler` and `HttpRequestCachePolicy` where the cached entry seems to get corrupted after a precise sequence.  The scenario goes as follow:

- request returns a 200 response with `Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0` and `Last-Modified`.
- a second request is made with `Last-Modified-Since` that returns a 500 response with `Cache-Control: private`.  In our case, it is caused by the IIS server when an error occurs during the request.
- a third request is sent.  It contains a `Last-Modified-Since` header which causes the server to respond with 304.
- The HttpClient result resolves to the 500 response.

My assumption is that the `Last-Modified-Since` header in the 3rd request should not have been present and is a bug.

The test was made in a sample console application in .NET 4.5 while using the `HttpRequestCacheLevel.Default` cache policy.  Trying the same test in a browser doesn't seem to reproduce the problem when navigating to the URL (I verified that max-age=0 was not present in the request).

What I am trying to understand is if it's a bug in the .NET framework, if we didn't use the API correctly or if we didn't use the response headers correctly.

Comment: In your 3rd request, I'm guessing that you didn't send a Last-Modified-Since from the HttpClient, but when the WinInNet proxy cache makes the call to the backend it does add a Last-Modified-Since header that you see in Fiddler.  Is that correct?  I must admit I'm surprised that WinINet cache is storing the 500 response, although it is technically allowed.

Comment: Based on what you are describing, it is not a bug.  If the 500 response has Cache-Control private, then it is telling the cache that the response can be cached.  When the next request is made, and the 500 response is considered stale, then a conditional GET is made to the backend to see if there is an updated representation.  The 304 says, no there is not, so HttpClient returns the cached 500.

Comment: @DarrelMiller I think the bug is with the conditional header being present since the 500 response didn't contain the Last-Modified header.  This header was for the 200 response.  What I would have expected is that the staleness is determined by heuristics since the 500 response didn't have age headers.  When the response is considered stale, I would expect a non-conditional request to the server.  This is actually what happens when using Etag instead of Last-Modified.

Comment: Agreed, if the 500 response doesn't contain a last-modified, then the cache has no business making a conditional GET to determine if it is fresh.  It wouldn't be the first bug found in WinInet cache!